# React nested routing render

Tags: reactjs

I'm quite new to React and have this kind of problem.
I have this routes:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path='/' name='/' component={App}>
            <Route path='a' component={A}></Route>
            <Route path='b' name='b' component={B}>
                <Route path='ba' component={BA}></Route>
                <Route path='bb' component={BB}></Route>
                <Route path='bc' component={BC}></Route>
            </Route>
            <Route path='c' name='c' component={C}></Route>
            <Route path='d' component={D}></Route>
        </Route>
    </Router>
```

First level nest(f.e. a,b,c,d) works fine and renders all I need.
But second level route renders only first level route data.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is:

`<Route path='b' name='b' component={B}>` <- Renders side nav with its data.

```
<Route path='ba' component={BA}></Route>
<Route path='bb' component={BB}></Route>
<Route path='bc' component={BC}></Route> <- Each route renders its data and has parent route side nav(active link).
```

So the parent route is this:

```
B = React.createClass(
    render: ->
        setActiveLink(this.props.location.pathname)
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-2">
                <div className="panel panel-default">
                    <NavPanel links={nav_panel_data.links} />   
                </div>  
            </div>
            {
                if this.props.children
                    {this.props.children}
                else
                    <div className="col-md-10"> 
                        <h1>Graph CS</h1>
                    </div>
            }
        </div>  
)
```

I thought that, when you change route it re-render to show children. But it seems it doesn't have children property and always render 'Graph CS'.
So the question is how can I render 2-nd lvl routes(like 'ba', 'bb')?

Answer (score 0):

Well based on your current route configuration, one of (ba, bb, bc) should render as the current children of B 
whenever your router matches a path like this `B >> ba or B >> bb or B >> bc`. Take a look at a code snnipet

```
{
                this.props.children ? this.props.children :  <BlankComponent/>
 }
```

Comment: Im doing similar like that in creation of `B` class

Comment: But still it doesnt render